# How to serialized generic class?

Tags: scala, serialization, slick, json4s

I have following case class

```
case class UserId(value: String) extends MappedTo[String]
```

(`MappedTo` is a generic id case class of `slick.typesafe`)
and I declare its serializer in json4s

```
case object IdSerializer extends CustomSerializer[UserId](format => ( {
    case JString(s) => UserId(s)
    case JNull | JNothing => null
  }, {
    case i: UserId => JString(i.value)
    case JNull | JNothing => null
  }))
```

The problem is that I have more than 20 id fields like that, and I don't want to declare serializer for each of it. Is there a way to do it for `MappedTo` so it can be applied to all of its subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you don't need to define your own serializer at all; case classes have a simple serialization method defined for them by the compiler, and [Json4s will use that](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serialization). If your other ID fields are members of a case class, they won't need one either.

Edit:

I gotcha. I'm reluctant to suggest this, since it is just patching over the real problem, which is the large number of case classes you are using, but something like this might work:

```
class IdSerializer[T] extends CustomSerializer[T <: MappedTo](format => ( {
    case JString(s) => new T(s)
    case JNull | JNothing => null
  }, {
    case i: T => JString(i.value)
    case JNull | JNothing => null
  }))
```

So for UserID, you would call `IdSerializer[UserID]`. A better solution is to stop using so many case classes, but maybe that isn't an option for you. Shrugs.

Comment: Yes json4s can serialize most of case classes. However, with `UserId(value:String)`  its serialization is `{userId:{value:....}}` which is not what I expect. So I created a custom serialization to make it like `{userId:...}`

Comment: Oh, I can see why you might want to do that. I'll update my answer.